# Convert row to column using pivot

Tags: pivot

This is my table now.

```
Name    PhoneType   Number
a   Cellular    303-333-3333
a   WorkPHone   444-444-4444
b   Workphone   222-222-2222
c   Cellular    111-111-1111
c   WorkPHone   333-333-3333
c   HomePhone   888-888-8888
d   Cellular    999-999-9999
d   WorkPHone   777-777-7777
d   HomePhone   111-222-3333
```

I want to convert to:

```
Name    Cellular    Workphone   Homephone
a   303-333-3333    444-444-4444    222-222-2222
b   222-222-2222        
c   111-111-1111    333-333-3333    888-888-8888
d   999-999-9999    777-777-7777    111-222-3333
```

I tried Pivot but can't do because I can't use aggregation function on phone number since it is nvarchar. How can I convert.

Answer (score 0):

You can use alternate to pivot using select query as below.

```
with xx as(
select 'a' namee,'cellular' typee,'303-333-3333' numberr from dual union all
select 'a' namee,'WorkPHone' typee,'444-444-4444' numberr from dual union all
select 'b' namee,'WorkPHone' typee,'222-222-2222' numberr from dual union all
select 'c' namee,'cellular' typee,'111-111-1111' numberr from dual union all
select 'c' namee,'WorkPHone' typee,'333-333-3333' numberr from dual union all
select 'c' namee,'HomePhone' typee,'888-888-8888' numberr from dual 
)
select 
 x.namee,
 max(case when x.typee='cellular' then x.numberr else '' end) as CELLULAR,
 max(case when x.typee='WorkPHone' then x.numberr else ''  end) as WORKPHONE,
 max(case when x.typee='HomePhone' then x.numberr else ''  end) as HOMEPHONE
from xx x
group by x.namee
order by x.namee;
```

**EDIT:**

xx table should be replaced with your table name. Assume that your table is named as my_table , the final query would be:

```
select x.Name , 
max(case when x.PhoneType='cellular' then x.Number else '' end) as CELLULAR,
max(case when x.PhoneType='WorkPHone' then x.Number else '' end) as WORKPHONE,
max(case when x.PhoneType='HomePhone' then x.Number else '' end) as HOMEPHONE 
from 
my_table x 
group by x.Name 
order by x.Name;
```

Comment: This is good but if you have only six rows but I have 100K rows and it will not be possible for the data i have, right?

Comment: xx table should be replaced with your table name. Assume that your table is named as my_table , the query would  be: select 
 x.Name   ,
 max(case when x.PhoneType='cellular' then x.Number else '' end) as CELLULAR,
 max(case when x.PhoneType='WorkPHone' then x.Number else ''  end) as WORKPHONE,
 max(case when x.PhoneType='HomePhone' then x.Number else ''  end) as HOMEPHONE
from xx x
group by x.Name
order by x.Name;

Comment: @NDuwal: Answer edited. I don't think this would cause an issue for more number of rows. The With Clause is just a dummy test data. You can check the same in your environment and let us know.